# Dynamic creating controls in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create controls dynamically in asp.net mvc4 but having some issues and need some suggestions as well. The following statement in the below is not working it shows me error line beneath "row.Options"
                               @for (var o in row.Options )

Beside this, can i dynamically create dropdownlist or dropdownlistfor if yes then how can i assign name and values according to current scenario?

**View**

```
            @foreach(var row in Model.Controls) {
                var i = 0;
                <div>                        
                     <label>@row.Caption</label>
                     @if (row.ControlType == "text") {
                        <input type="text" name="@row.Name" />
                     } else if (row.ControlType == "select") {

                        <select name="@row.Name">
                            @for (var o in row.Options ) {
                                <option value="@o.Value>">@o.Text</option>
                            }
                        </select>                             
                     }                                          
                </div>  
                i++;
            }
            </ul>
```

**View Model**

```
public List<SelectListItem> MembershipTypeList { get; set; }

public class Controls
{
    public string Caption {get; set;}
    public string ControlType {get; set;} 
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
    public ActionResult Signup()
    {
        signup.MembershipTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "Student  £18.00",
            Value = "Student"
        });

        signup.MembershipTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "Associate  £18.00",
            Value = "Associate"
        });

        signup.Controls = new List<Controls>();
        signup.Controls.Add(new Controls() { Caption = "Age", ControlType = "text", Name = "txtage" });
        signup.Controls.Add(new Controls() { Caption = "Name", ControlType = "text", Name = "txtname" });
        signup.Controls.Add(new Controls() { Caption = "Membership", ControlType = "select", Name = "txtmembership", Options = signup.MembershipTypeList });

        return View("Signup", signup);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your code is invalid here:

```
<select name="@row.Name">
    @for (var o in row.Options ) {
        <option value="@o.Value>">@o.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Remove the "`>`" from `@o.Value>`

Rendering as it is breaks the html.

Fix:

```
<select name="@row.Name">
    @foreach (var o in row.Options ) {
        <option value="@o.Value">@o.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: it was simple error i just had to put "@foreach" instead of @for... thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

I think it might just be an extra angle bracket causing this, try changing to:

```
<option value="@o.Value">@o.Text</option>
```